# Polynomial - problem in dots

Tags: functions

Find polynomial f(x) with real coefictions that satisfied: 
 
$(x+1)*f(x-1) = (x-2)*f(x)$

I find that $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)=0$. 
Please help with this task.

Comment: Can we start with $$\dfrac{f(x-1)}{x-2}=\dfrac{f(x)}{x+1}=a_0+a_1x+\cdots$$ and equate the coefficients of different powers of $x$

Comment: @AnuragA This does not work if $\alpha = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

You've already found that this polynomial has roots $\pm 1$, hence it is divisible by $(x-1)(x+1)$. By a direct computation we can shpw that this polynomial does not fit our equation, hence we will consider the polynomial $(x-1)(x+1)(x+k)$ and find this constant $k$.

WE write

$$f(x)(x-2)=(x-1)(x+1)(x+k)(x-2) = (x+1)f(x-1) = (x+1)(x-2)x(x+k-1).$$
After simplifications, we obtain

$$ (x-1) (x+k)   =  x(x+k-1).$$Clearly, $k=0$ fits.

The answer is $f(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$. Now proving that this polynomial is the unique (up to a multiplicative constant) solution of this equation is another question.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show that $f(0)=0$ (just take $x=1$ in the equation), and find that the solution must be divisible by $x^3-x$.